# CSS menu hide behind Nivo Slider's navigator in Adobe Dreamweaver

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, dreamweaver

CSS menu hide behind Nivo Slider's navigator in Adobe Dreamweaver. I have tried to use a position relative for menu first level and add position absolute for a menu 2 level but does't work for me.

[image: CSS Menu hiding]

NIVO SLIDER:

```
.theme-orman .nivo-controlNav-bg {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -15px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 44px;
    z-index: 100;
    background: url(../images/slider_nav_bg.png) no-repeat  
}

.theme-orman .nivo-controlNav {
    position:absolute;
    left: 472px;
    bottom: 4px;
    margin-left:-30px; /* Tweak this to center bullets */
    z-index: 101;
}
.theme-orman .nivo-controlNav a {
    display:block;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    background:url(../images/slider_nav_button.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
    margin-right:7px;
    float:left;
}
```

CSS MENU:

```
    .ddsmoothmenu{
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul{
    z-index:100;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

/*Top level list items*/
.ddsmoothmenu ul li{
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

/*Top level menu link items style*/
.ddsmoothmenu ul li a {
    display: block;
    height: 46px;
    width: 106px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #FCFCC7; 
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    outline: none;
    background: url(../images/templatemo_menu_item.jpg) 
}

* html .ddsmoothmenu ul li a{ /*IE6 hack to get sub menu links to behave       correctly*/
display: inline-block;
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li a.selected, .ddsmoothmenu ul li a:hover { /*CSS class     that's dynamically added to the currently active menu items' LI A element*/
    color: #EB1765;
    background: url(../images/templatemo_menu_hover2.png) no-repeat
}

/*1st sub level menu*/
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 184px;
    margin: 0 0 0 3px;
    display: none; /*collapse all sub menus to begin with*/
    visibility: hidden;
    background: #F0E11A
}

/*Sub level menu list items (undo style from Top level List Items)*/
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li{  
display: list-item;
float: none;
}

/*All subsequent sub menu levels vertical offset after 1st level sub menu */
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li ul{
top: 0;
}

/* Sub level menu links style */
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a{
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 140px; /*width of sub menus*/
    margin: 0 3px 0 1px;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 5px 22px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: left;
    background: none;
    color: #161AF7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bab5b0

}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li .last {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a.selected, .ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a:hover {
    color: #EDEA15;
    width: 139px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background: #CF178E;
}


/* Holly Hack for IE \*/
* html .ddsmoothmenu{height: 1%;} /*Holly Hack for IE7 and below*/


/* ######### CSS classes applied to down and right arrow images  #########  */

.downarrowclass{
position: absolute;
top: 12px;
right: 7px;
}

.rightarrowclass{
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
right: 5px;
}

/* ######### CSS for shadow added to sub menus  ######### */

.ddshadow{
position: absolute;
: 0;
top: 0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
}

.toplevelshadow{ /*shadow opacity. Doesn't work in IE*/
opacity: 0.5;
}

/* menu */
```

Comment: z-index is lower than slider controls

Comment: @charlietfl I have changed z-index  but doesn't work for the menu.

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl z-index work for slider nav background & slider nav button not for the menu ul{ . How do I create a demo?

Comment: any sandbox site like jsfiddle.net, plunkr.co, codepen.io etc. There are quite a few choices. Use a cdn to include required resources

Comment: now problem solved by adding a position relative to 1st level menu .ddsmoothmenu ul{
     position: relative; /* add a position */
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style-type: none;
     z-index:102; /* changed from 100 */
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
.ddsmoothmenu ul{
    position: relative; /* add a position */
    z-index:102; /* changed from 100 */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

The `z-index` is the level on the screen. The dots have 100 and the menu has 100. So it will be drawn behind the dots. So you just need to change the level.

Comment: I have changed z-index  but doesn't work for the menu.

Comment: now problem solved by adding a position relative to 1st level menu .ddsmoothmenu ul{
     position: relative; /* add a position */
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style-type: none;
     z-index:102; /* changed from 100 */
    }